# eclipse e4 enabling showView menu

Tags: rcp, e4

I've got an RCP4 application based on an e4xmi model with 3 parts. I just want to add a menu like the "Window" menu of Eclipse which contains a "Show view" submenu which opens a dialog to open a part. How can I do to reuse this submenu ? 
I've tried to use an extension point to "org.eclipse.ui.menus" by adding a menu called window and a with the command "org.eclipse.ui.views.showView" :

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
      <menu
            id="window"
            label="Window">
         <command
               commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
               label="Show Progress"
               style="push">
            <parameter
                  name="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
                  value="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProgressView">
            </parameter>
         </command>
      </menu>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

But when I run my plugin nothing happens in the main menu, no "Window" menu is created. Any idea of the problem ?

May be is there an conflict with e4xmi application model ?

Tahnks by advance for your help, I'm new in RCP :-)

Answer (score 0):

`org.eclipse.ui.menus` is only for Eclipse 3.x compatibilty mode RCPs. You can't use any `org.eclipse.ui.xxx` extension points or classes in a pure e4 RCP.

This means that you can't use most Eclipse 3.x menus in an e4 application - you have to write them from scratch yourself. The same applies to existing editors and views.

To add a menu item to show a part defined in your e4xmi file you can add a Handled Menu Item or Direct Menu Item in the e4xmi file. The handler for the menu item should use the `EPartService` `showPart` method to show a part:

```java
@Inject
EPartService partService;

partService.showPart("part id", PartState.Activate);
```

But again you can't use this to show the existing progress view as that is a 3.x compatibility view.